# CSS rendering on IE help needed

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am pulling my hair trying to find a fix for this problem. If you go to [this site](http://www.actormayhem.com/) you will see that (under IE) the slider and the menu on the top is broken. Works fine under all modern browsers.

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks.

**Edit:** Want to add that the [original site design](http://themeforest.net/item/spectre/44817) works fine under IE. I did a massive amount of editing under the hood and somewhere along the line this one was broken that I can't seem to find a fix for. Since I did a lot of customization, I think it seems unfair to ask the original author for a fix (and he is not very responsive either).

Comment: I'm on a Mac, so I'm no help for you tonight, but you may want to try asking at doctype.com.

Comment: BTW, interesting site concept (I'm on MM, #98472)

Comment: No answer yet, but I upvote your question for funniest IE quirk I have ever seen. When selecting the piece of "Contact" below the main menu, it highlights the letters of the one in the bar! Crazy!

Answer (score 1):

The document invalid. In particular, there is a `<style>` element before the Doctype. This triggers Quirks mode and causes browsers to become very inconsistent (e.g. IE emulates a log of bugs from IE 5.5).

Always work in [standards mode](http://gutfeldt.ch/matthias/articles/doctypeswitch.html) and perform [basic automated QA](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.actormayhem.com%2F&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).

Answer (score 0):

I can't check it for you, since I've not got access to IE right now, but I've often found that adding `position:relative` to misbehaving elements is something of an IE magic bullet.

Answer (score 0):

No fix but a lead: the issue with the menu bar is one of IE's mysterious float positioning bugs, as can be demonstrated by putting `<div style="clear: both">xxx</div>` after the navbar `ul`. (Note that it won't work if the div has no content!)

*stuff about box model deleted: as David Dorward mentions this is caused by quirks mode, and moving the style down past the doctype causes the slider to behave sensibly.*

Comment: Thanks. That fixed the slider/box problem by adding those line to ie.css http://www.actormayhem.com/wp-content/themes/spectre/css/ie.css. It looks a lot better and I can live with that. Now I am hoping to get the "menu" thingie fixed.

Comment: No, don't do that! Look at David's response instead when it coems to the slider.